# Set androidTest.apk version code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I use `./gradlew assembleAndroidTest` to create `app-debug-androidTest.apk`, but the versionCode for apk is always `0`. Is there any to set the versionCode for `app-debug-androidTest.apk`.

Thanks!

For normal apk, I can set in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:versionCode="110"
android:versionName="3.0.17 alpha"
```

or in `build.gralde`:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.searchui"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 84
    versionName "9.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

But when during instrumented tests, there are generated two .apk files. And the smaller one is app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk and it's versionCode is 0.

Updated on 2017/8/4:

I think it's very difficult to do this because the `com.android.application` gradle plugin didn't provider androidTest apk versionCode setting.

So I just put a `version.xml` to `src/androidTest/res/values` folder:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="versionCode">111</integer>
</resources>
```

Use this to fake versionCode.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy the `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` to `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`

then add `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` in `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your manifest

```
 android:versionCode="110"
 android:versionName="3.0.17 alpha"
```

you can set your desired version code and name

Comment: For normal apk, this works, but for androidTest apk. [It has be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244998/androidmanifest-in-androidtest-directory-being-ignored)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **/app/build.gradle**.
There you can give versionCode and versionName
For eg

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your package name"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. dump test apk
   `java -jar ~/apktool_2.4.0.jar d ./app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk`
2. copy AndroidManifest.xml to androidTest
   `cp app-debug-androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml app/src/androidTest/`
3. add `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` in AndroidManifest.xml
4. rebuild test apk