# How to make android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" only for instrumentation tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, mockwebserver

I'm using [RESTMock](https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock) for my instrumentation tests, but it only works if I set [`usesCleartextTraffic`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) to `true` in my manifest. I only want that to be true for instrumentation tests, though. Is there a way to do that?

I tried creating a new manifest file in the `androidTest` folder. The tests run but they fail like `usesCleartextTraffic` is still `false`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package">

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />

</manifest>
```

I know that RESTMock supports https starting from version 0.3.2, but I'd rather not have to deal with it. I actually followed their guide and ended up with this error from OkHttp3:

`java.lang.AssertionError: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: The BC provider no longer provides an implementation for KeyPairGenerator.RSA.  Please see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html for more details.`

Any ideas?

---

#### EDIT:

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884436/2352699) answer and moved this manifest I created to the `debug` source folder and then it worked. Now the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` option is only applied to my debug build, which is used by the instrumentation tests, so it works, but it still doesn't feel like the proper solution.

Comment: Not sure why `AndroidManifes.xml` in `androidTest` directory didn't work for you, but it worked for me. I've added an answer with the exact details that worked for me, just in case is just a small detail. Let me know if it solves your issue. :)

Answer (score 6):

For me the solution is to add a simple `AndroidManifest.xml` in `androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`. This is also mentioned in the answer you reference, but in that case it didn't work because old tooling didn't merge this `AndroidManifest.xml`.

So, inside `androidTest` directory, and next to `java` directory, I have the following:

```
~/source/my-library/src/androidTest develop*
❯ ls
AndroidManifest.xml java
```

With this `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.mypackage.mylibrary">

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting this answer together! Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I have all the tooling up to date, so I'm really not sure what might be wrong.

Comment: I would check whether `android:networkSecurityConfig` or `android:usesCleartextTraffic` is being merge in from other module. For this, I think your best bet is to check the merge report (e.g. `manifest-merger-release-report.txt` or `manifest-merger-debug-report.txt`). Using the Merged Manifest tab seems to not provide enough detail. Notice that, for example from my tests `app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt` is the right report, even for instrumented tests.