# Instrumented test uses main AndroidManifest instead of the test version

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-testing, instrumented-test

I am trying to uses OkHttp in some Android instrumented tests, but I get the following error:

> java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy

For API 28 and higher, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) says that `android:usesCleartextTraffic` should be set in that case.

If I set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in my `main/AndroidManifest.xml`, then it works. But that is not what I want; I want to enable this only for tests.

So I created *myproject/app/src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml* with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</manifest>
```

And it does what I expect: the generated instrumented apk (*./app/build/intermediates/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk*) has an AndroidManifest that correctly sets `usesCleartextTraffic` (I checked with `apktool` directly in the *app-debug-androidTest.apk*.

But it seems like it doesn't matter, because anyway at runtime it will somehow rely on the AndroidManifest of the main app: *./app/build/intermediates/apk/debug/app-debug.apk*. If I set `usesCleartextTraffic=true` in the main AndroidManifest, then it works. But that's not what I want; I want it only for the instrumented tests!

What is the relation between *app-debug-androidTest.apk* and *app-debug.apk* when running instrumented tests, and how to make the *androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml* have priority (or be merged) into the main one when running the instrumented tests?

Comment: Did you try the solutions offered here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26244998/8331157

Comment: Yes. The things I have seen is that people have been struggling to get the AndroidManifest.xml to be merged correctly. But in my case it seems like it is, but `usesCleartextTraffic` is just ignored somehow.

Comment: Hmm it feels like this is not possible. I'll keep it open in case someone ever has a solution, but it feels like I can't override the "main" AndroidManifest just for the androidTests.

Comment: Well it may work when testing a library (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54090348/1368342), but in my case I am testing an app.