# Internet access in Instrumented Test

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-espresso

I'm trying to reach one of our servers in an Android Instrumented Test.
I'm running the test on a device with Android 10 and I obtain the following Exception:

```
Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

To avoid this I've tried (I'm using kotlin)

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var runtimePermission = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
```

but in this case I've got thi error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions
```

Even the following code has no success:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                "pm grant " + context.getPackageName()
                        + " android.permission.INTERNET");
}
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal?

[UPDATED] Here is a minimal test:

```
class Minimal {

@Rule
@JvmField
var runtimePermission: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)

@Test
fun minimalReproducible() {

    val buffer = CharArray(2000)
    val url = URL("https://example.net/new-message.php")
    val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
    connection.requestMethod = "POST"

    val urlParameters: String = ""      // buildParameterUrlString(params)

    connection.doOutput = true
    val outputStream = DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream)
    outputStream.writeBytes(urlParameters)
    outputStream.flush()
    outputStream.close()
    val responseCode = connection.responseCode
  }
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand how your current code snippets fit together or what they even have to do with testing. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice updated with a minimal example test, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing this on your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Where is the Manifest for the tests?

Comment: This response can help you create your manifest for the tests if you don't have one yet 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884436/11611305

Comment: It works! Please, expand the answer saying where to put the Manifest for tests; in fact, I didn't know it was possible to have a Manifest for the tests.

Comment: Test manifest is not needed. You must add the permission to the module manifest. This is a common error when creating modules, when modules have no permissions and app has all the permissions. Best practice is to declare the needed permissions in every module: the compiler will then make the merged Manifest.